# Form submission with Stripe and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm having a problem submitting a new customer form to stripe. If I fill out the form from top to bottom, Email, Credit Card Info, and hit submit, the form fails ("There was a problem with your credit card"). On stripes end, the email is sent but the card info is blank.

However if I fill out the credit card info first, hit submit, AND THEN fill in the Email, everything works as it should. A new subscription is made on the app and a new customer is created in stripe.

I'm sure there is something I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Signing up for <%= @subscription.plan.name %></h1>
 <strong><%= @subscription.plan.price %></strong> per month!</p>

 <%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
   <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
     <div class="error_messages">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
       <ul>
       <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.text_field :email, "data-stripe" => "email" %>
   </div>

   <% if @subscription.stripe_card_token.present? %>
     <p>Credit card has been provided.</p>
   <% else %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
       <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, "data-stripe" => "number" %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
       <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, "data-stripe" => "cvc" %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
       <%= text_field_tag :card_month, nil, name: nil, "data-stripe" => "exp-month", class: "input-mini", "placeholder" => "MM" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_year, nil, name: nil, "data-stripe" => "exp-year", class: "input-mini", "placeholder" => "YYYY" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   <div id="stripe_error">
     <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

subcriptions_controller.rb

```
    class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @subscriptions = Subscription.all
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def subscription_params
      params.require(:subscription).permit(:plan_id, :email, :stripe_card_token)
    end
end
```

The model subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  belongs_to :plan
  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(card: stripe_card_token, email: email, plan: plan_id)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
end
```

And finally, the javascript (mostly from stripe's documentation, but slightly modified):

```
// This identifies your website in the createToken call below
Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#new_subscription');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.find($('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

jQuery(function($) {
      $('#new_subscription').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Thanks for reading! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but it couldn't possibly be related to the order the fields are filled out.

Comment: Yes, something else is afoot. One other clue, if it helps, is that if I fill in any of the credit card details, say the Card Number but no expiry dates or CVC and hit submit, Stripe will send an error like "missing expiry date" or whatever. If I then complete the form and hit submit it passes and works. It's like the stripe elements aren't being seen or initialized somehow, when you submit the form in its entirety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what's going on here. After a lot more testing I realized that if I hit refresh on the page, and then filled out the form and submitted it, it worked every time. But, if I navigated to the subscription_path through the app, it would create an error unless you manually refreshed the page after getting there.

So...after a lot of digging around I found out that the problem is with Turbolinks. This post helped me figure out how to fix the problem: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links). From what I can gather, jQuery wasn't loading up Stripe.js because of turbo-links.

There are a couple options how to fix it.

1. Disable turbo-links
2. Add some code to your javascript (see link above)
3. Add the jquery-turbolinks gem which helps jQuery play nice with turbo-links.

(I chose option 3 as it seemed to be the easiest solution).

Anyway, now the form works!

Comment: or you can specify that the link in question doesn't use Turbolinks